# How to change both date and time in a datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to set the time and date in my query based one the following conditions:

1. if time in MyDate < 9:00 then set the time to 9:00
2. If time in 9:00 < MyDate < 15:00 then set the time to 16:00
3. If time is MyDate > 15:00 then set the time to 9:00 and the day to day+1

I have the two first conditions in place and works fine, but cannot combine changes in both time and date. How can I do that?

The code below works fine for the two first conditions!

```
Case When cast(MyDate as TIME) < '09:00:00' Then DATEADD(Hour, 9, CAST(CAST(PayoutDtApplication As Date) As Datetime)) 

Case When cast(MyDate as TIME) < '09:00:00' Then DATEADD(Hour, 9, CAST(CAST(PayoutDtApplication As Date) As Datetime))
```

THanks

Comment: Have you tried `NewDate = '2018-03-02 09:00:00'`?

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: Do you want to add few hours in your mayDate?

Comment: Sorry, a correction here: NewDate = 2018-03-02 09:00:00

Comment: `DATEADD(MINUTE,975,mayDate)`???

Comment: Hi Amit, no, it is both day and hour: so it is like under a certain condition I want to add one they and set the time to 9:00.

Comment: Lamu, why 975? don't get what you mean?

Comment: this numbers can varries based on the data I get, just wanted to say I need to set the time to 9:00 and day+1 for all dates I get.  I have different dates.

Comment: @VBS there are 975 minutes between `2018-03-01 16:45:00` and `2018-03 02-09:00:00`. Perhaps you should look up the [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function (personallyI feel it's a function that requires little explanation on what it's doing, unlike other functions such as `STUFF`, but perhaps not). You need to explain your logic here. We're all guessing here. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50251743/edit) your post and elaborate on your goals and needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, based on the following comment:

> this numbers can varries based on the data I get, just wanted to say I need to set the time to 9:00 and day+1 for all dates I get. I have different dates.

I'm **guessing** that regardless of the time, the OP wants to change the value to the following date at 09:00:00.

If so, one way to achieve it would be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 33, CONVERT(date,YourDateColumn)) AS NewDate
FROM YourTable;
```

Again, this is guesswork. If the OP elaborates, I'll be happy to expand my answer, or remove it if it's irrelevant.

Edit: Based on the OP's new logic from their edit:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (YourDate datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('2018-05-09T08:57:00'),
       ('2018-05-09T14:26:37'),
       ('2018-05-09T19:24:01');
GO

SELECT YourDate,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(time, YourDate) < '09:00:00' THEN DATEADD(HOUR,9,CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(date,YourDate)))
            WHEN CONVERT(time, YourDate) > '15:00:00' THEN DATEADD(HOUR,33,CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(date,YourDate)))
            ELSE DATEADD(HOUR,15,CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(date,YourDate))) END AS NewDate
FROM #Sample;

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

The double `CONVERT` (`CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(date...`) is because the data type `date` isn't compatible with `DATEADD(HOUR...`. I have used `datetime2` as this should be used over `datetime` now.